# Layout on all devices, what are the steps to follow?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I am facing an issue of how to proceed with my designer and then on my app ( iOS app using Size class ) to make the layout as required.

Here his how we proceed:

1 / The designer of my company is preparing the UX/UI on illustrator, he is preparing them on 320 × 568 ( is that the way ? )

2 / Export the images as .pdf File @1x based on his UX

3 / I am using  Size Class @ storyboard

So :

(a) I have an image ( a circle ) which needs to be in the middle of the screen.

(b) The designer's UX ( based on iPhone 5 ) has an image 200*200px, I set the constraint : center horizontally & vertically. looks good for iPhone 5, 4s

(c) Then on the iPhone 6, 6Plus it looks too small in the middle of the screen, so I decide to set different constraint to have a ratio according to the Width, still correct ?

Here is what goes wrong :

(d)  the based image @1x is 200*200px and with the ratio my UIImageView becomes ~260*260px and the image is not well rendered.

How to proceed ?

1 / Should my designer export me an image.pdf @1x for different sizes, 200px and 260px, and I'll change the image I am using in the code to fit different devices ?

2 / Should I keep one image for all size and play with only with the constraint ?

note : I usually use the Slicing when it is about shape that I can Slice.

Answer (score 0):

Your designer should be designing your resolution for the maximum screen size and exporting graphics as PDF's. You should then be importing your graphics as PDF's.

1. In your image.assets folder drag and drop your .pdf graphic into the folder
2. Select the image you just added
3. In the attributes inspector on the right bar change scale factors to "Single Vector"

Comment: Does pdf work for color graphics? I was under the impression it's only good for icon type art.

Comment: Vector(PDF) images/graphics have many advantages to other graphic types. The only real downside of vectors is file size.

Comment: But they are typically smaller than having files for one image at 2x, 3x - especially with big images right? I just wasn't aware I could use it for all assets, I've only been using them for monochrome assets.

Comment: I'm not positive on whether cumulative assets, assuming PNG's, at different scales would be smaller than one PDF file. But I've never had a problem with using only PDF's. If you were laying out a collection of images, dozens, PNG's would be the way to go. For graphics and other UI elements, vector graphics are your friend.

Comment: spacemonkey, thanks for your answer - I know about how using PDFs, as i am using it since a while now - but if I understood you well, 
1 / my designer should work on iPhone 6 plus all the time..., and keeping in mind that what she does should fit to a 3.5inch screen ? 
2 / exporting the PDF @1x as she have it on her illustrator file within a iPhone 6

Comment: There is no perfect solution. I don't know what your exact layout is but designing up to the largest layout size is your best option. You might have to tinker with the layout for the 3.5inch screen, that's tricky no matter what your layout is. The 3.5 inch screen is always a bit of a pain to get the layout to sync with the other size screens. 

Yes you only need to export the PDF @1x.